# Dependencies on a queue deletion. We plan on removing (50+ queues)

Tags: metadata, package-dependency

I need to delete a bunch of queues in the org (maybe be over a 50) that are no longer used.
As I delete each of them I do see the dependencies.Is there a way I could see its references all in one place without actually deleting them?